# How do you change the width of a Y-axis in a D3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a simple, working bar chart in D3, configured as follows:

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;
        //var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

        var svg = d3.select("#arrChart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.csv("/chart-arr", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .attr("width", "150")
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".91em")
      .attr("width", "150")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});

</script>
```

Right now the Y-axis is not wide enough to accommodate the text labels.  My question is, how can I make the Y-axis wider to accommodate longer text labels on the Y-axis?

I tried attr("width") and various other tweaks but nothing is working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by changing your margin left:

`var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 70},`

**NOTE:** Please try to always state which version of d3 you are using because v3 and v5 are very different in their APIs etc.

Also, always try to include some dummy data, so that the question is a minimal verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 70},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;
//var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#arrChart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.csv("/chart-arr", function(error, data) {
    const data = [
      {date: '2020-01', value: '15000'},
      {date: '2020-02', value: '17000'},
      {date: '2020-03', value: '10000'},
      {date: '2020-04', value: '9000'}
    ];
    
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });
    
    //console.log(data)

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .attr("width", "150")
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(0) translate(60,-20)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".91em")
      .attr("width", "150")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrChart"></div>
```

Output:

[image]